# DynamoDB Querying in Python (Count with GroupBy)

Tags: python, twitter, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

This may be trivial, but I loaded a local DynamoDB instance with 30GB worth of Twitter data that I aggregated.

The primary key is id (tweet_id from the Tweet JSON), and I also store the date/text/username/geocode.

I basically am interested in mentions of two topics (let's say "Bees" and "Booze"). **I want to get a count of each of those by state by day.**

So by the end, I should know for each state, how many times each was mentioned on a given day. And I guess it'd be nice to export that as a CSV or something for later analysis.

Some issues I had with doing this...

First, the geocode info is a tuple of [latitude, longitude] so for each entry, I need to map that to a state. That I can do.

Second, is the most efficient way to do this to go through each entry and manually check if it contains a mention of either keyword and then have a dictionary for each that maps the date/location/count?

**EDIT:**

Since it took me 20 hours to load all the data into my table, I don't want to delete and re-create it. Perhaps I should create a **global secondary index (?)** and use that to search other fields in a query? That way I don't have to scan everything. Is that the right track?

**EDIT 2:**

Well, since the table is on my computer locally I should be OK with just using expensive operations like a Scan right?

So if I did something like this:

```
query = table.scan(
     FilterExpression=Attr('text').contains("Booze"),
     ProjectionExpression='id, text, date, geo', 
     Limit=100)
```

And did one scan for each keyword, then I would be able to go through the resulting filtered list and get a count of mentions of each topic for each state on a given day, right?

**EDIT3:**

```
response = table.scan(
   FilterExpression=Attr('text').contains("Booze"),
   Limit=100)
//do something with this set
while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
   response = table.scan(
      FilterExpression=Attr('text').contains("Booze"),
      Limit=100, 
      ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey']
   )
   //do something with each batch of 100 entries
```

So something like that, for both keywords. That way I'll be able to go through the resulting filtered set and do what I want (in this case, figure out the location and day and create a final dataset with that info). Right?

**EDIT 4**

If I add:

```
ProjectionExpression='date, location, user, text'
```

into the scan request, I get an error saying "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Invalid ProjectionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: location". How do I fix that?

NVM I got it. Answer is to look into ExpressionAttributeNames (see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ExpressionPlaceholders.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, scanning the table for "Booze" and counting the items in the result should give you the total count. Please note that you need to do **recursive scan** until LastEvaluatedKey is null.

Refer [exclusive start key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#API_Scan_RequestSyntax) as well.

[Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)

**EDIT:-**

Yes, the code looks good. One thing to note, the result set wouldn't always contain 100 items. Please refer the LIMIT definition below (not same as SQL database).

> Limit — (Integer) The maximum number of items to evaluate (not
>   necessarily the number of matching items). If DynamoDB processes the
>   number of items up to the limit while processing the results, it stops
>   the operation and returns the matching values up to that point, and a
>   key in LastEvaluatedKey to apply in a subsequent operation, so that
>   you can pick up where you left off. Also, if the processed data set
>   size exceeds 1 MB before DynamoDB reaches this limit, it stops the
>   operation and returns the matching values up to the limit, and a key
>   in LastEvaluatedKey to apply in a subsequent operation to continue the
>   operation. For more information, see Query and Scan in the Amazon
>   DynamoDB Developer Guide.

Comment: I updated with some sample code using that approach. Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: quick question. If I add ProjectionExpression='date, location, user, text' then I get an error saying "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Invalid ProjectionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: location". How do I fix that?

Comment: Nvm I got it. Answer is to look at ExpressionAttributeNames.